# Funções instanciadas

Tags: javascript

```
function relogio(elemento){
    console.log(elemento)
}
$('[wm-relogio]').each((i,e) => new relogio(e))
```

Qual a diferença entre `relogio` e `new relogio` instanciado?
Sendo que os 2 funcionam?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Primeiro exemplo

A diferença é que um é uma simples função e quando você usa o `new` você cria um objeto, veja este pequeno exemplo, estou chamando a função e o objeto, perceba que ao chama a função o retorno foi `undefined` enquanto ao chama o objeto ele me retorna um objeto `{}`.

```js
function relogio(elemento){

}
   
console.log(relogio("teste"));
console.log(new relogio("teste"));
```

## Segundo exemplo

Veja este outro exemplo, quando crio o "car1" ele é um objeto, ou seja, eu criei o objeto, eu criei uma instância, agora "car1" existe, porem quando uso a função "Car" e atribuo a "car2" eu não criei uma instância, ou seja, a função só executa e nada mais que isso, ela não cria um novo objeto.

Então ao tentar executar "car2.make", gera um erro, já que "car2" não é um objeto, "car2" e simplesmente uma variável com o valor `undefined`.

```js
function Car(make, model, year) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
}

var car1 = new Car('Eagle', 'Talon TSi', 1993);
var car2 = Car('Eagle', 'Talon TSi', 1993);

console.log(car1.make);
console.log(car2.make);
```

## Terceiro exemplo utilizando o seu código

```
function relogio(elemento){
    console.log(elemento)
}
$('[wm-relogio]').each((i,e) => new relogio(e))
```

Você falou "Sendo que os 2 funcionam", funcionam parcialmente, você chama uma `array function`

```
(i,e) => new relogio(e)
```

Esta função é equivalente a

```
function(i, e){
    return new relogio(e);
}
```

Se você faz como o exemplo acima, ele vai retorna uma instância/objeto de "relogio", ao cria uma instância de relógio ele executa o seu construtor `console.log(elemento)`, mostrando o valor de "elemento" no `console`, porem se você faz

```
function(i, e){
    return relogio(e);
}
```

Sem a palavra reservada `new`, ele vai fazer o mesmo, porém sem retorna o objeto "relogio", ele vai simplesmente executar a função "relogio" e vai retorna `undefined`.

Então se a função precisar do objeto "relogio" você deve usar a palavra reservada `new`, porém se você não necessita deste retorno melhor utilizar sem a palavra `new`, assim evita de criar um objeto desnecessariamente.

## Conclusão

Quando você usa a palavra reservada `new` ela cria uma instância, e o que é uma instância é a criação de um objeto, podendo então usar este objeto, e quando eu executo uma função, ela simplesmente "faz o seu trabalho" e pronto, não cria algo novo.